# Proof that if A and B are connected sets, $A \cup B$ is connected iff $(\bar A \cap B) \cup (A \cap \bar B) \neq \emptyset$

Tags: general-topology, proof-writing, connectedness

The problem says: Let $(X,\tau)$ be a topological space so that $A,B \subset X$ are connected sets in said space.

For $M\subset X, \bar M$ refers to the closure of $M$.

Prove that $A \cup B$ is connected if and only if $(\bar A \cap B) \cup (A \cap \bar B) \neq \emptyset$.

I have no idea where to start. Can someone help me?

Comment: Hi thanks for your question. If you put "$" around your math expressions, they will be rendered proberly. Please also try to include your previous efforts and try to avoid "no clue" questions.

Comment: Thanks! I'm a first time poster so i'm really new to all this lol.

Comment: Do you have an intuitive picture of why you would expect this to be true? Maybe try visualising some examples in $\mathbb{R}^2$.

Comment: One direction has an answer on a pre-existing thread, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1976517/if-overlinea-cap-b-neq-emptyset-e-a-cup-b-prove-that-e-is-connected.

Comment: Hi, welcome to MSE! legionwhale's advice is great and I concur very strongly. Do you know the following two facts about connectedness: "if $C$ is connected then $\mathrm{cl}(C)$ is connected" and "if $X$ and $Y$ are connected and $X \cap Y \ne \emptyset$, then $X \cup Y$ is connected"? Do you have any ideas how you could use these in the "connected" case? On the other side, what "information" do you have in the "disconnected" case? How could you use this to make two open sets?

Comment: Thanks for the answers, everyone! Yes, I know those properties, but the expression in this case is so long that I get dizzy. Now that you bring it to my attention, I have a hunch that I should try to express A$\cup$B using its closure or something like that, but I have class now. I will try and come back in about 2 hours with the answer.

Comment: The dizziness is absolutely fair enough! I had a lecturer who would describe that as "symbol overload". Perhaps it would help to observe that the long non-equation is equivalent to "the closure of $A$ intersects $B$, or the closure of $B$ intersects $A$", which is a more helpful way to think about it I think. This means that in one direction, by symmetry all you need to do is show "if the closure of $A$ intersects $B$, then $A \cup B$ is connected", and for the converse you need to show "if the closure of $A$ is disjoint from $B$ and vice versa, then $A \cup B$ is disconnected".

Answer (score 0):

(For the statement to be correct, we need to assume that $A$ and $B$ are both nonempty.)

By definition, $A \cup B$ is **disconnected iff there are 2 disjoint nonempty open subsets (!) $X,Y$ of $A \cup B$ such that $X \cup Y = A \cup B$**.

The first step is to see that **if such $X$ and $Y$ exist, they must coincide with $A$ and $B$** (in either of the two ways), i.e. either $X=A, Y=B$ or $X=B, Y=A$. This follows from the non-emptyness of $A$ and observation that if $X \cap A \neq \emptyset$ and $X \cap B \neq \emptyset$, since both these intersections are open in $A$, this would mean that $A$ is be disconnected. Similarly, $B$ has to be fully contained in one of $X$ or $Y$. Also, neither $X$ nor $Y$ can be the full $A \cup B$ since they are disjoint nonempty subsets.

From this it follows that  $A \cup B$ is **disconnected iff** $A \cap B = \emptyset$ **and both $A$ and $B$ are open in $A \cup B$**.

From here it might be clearer how to go at showing that this is equivalent to the condition $cl(A) \cap B = \emptyset \land A \cap cl(B) = \emptyset$.

Answer (score 0):

The proof kinda depends on what (equivalent) definitions of closure and connectedness you've covered. Since you already mentioned that you want to try again with the excellent advice of the commenters, you might not need this explanation anymore, but here's an idea:

We can assume that $A$ and $B$ are nonempty, otherwise the result is trivial.
We first prove the implication $"\Leftarrow"$ by contraposition, so suppose
$A\cup B$ is not connected. Then there exist open sets $V,W\subset X$ such that $$(A\cup B)\cap V \neq \emptyset$$
$$(A\cup B)\cap W \neq \emptyset$$
(These conditions are the analogue of excluding empty sets when talking about connected spaces, here regarding the subspace topology on $A\cup B$) and
$$(V\cap W)\cap (A\cup B) = \emptyset$$
$$(A\cup B) \subset (V\cup W).$$
Notice that these are just translations of connectedness of the space $A\cup B$ with respect to the subspace topology.
Then, by connectedness of $A$ and $B$, both sets have to be contained in either $V$ or $W$, otherwise $V$ and $W$ would violate the connectedness of $A$ or $B$:
$$A\subset (A\cup B)\subset (V\cup W)\text{ and } B\subset (A\cup B)\subset (V\cup W),$$ which can only be remedied by assuming that the intersection of $A$ and $B$ with one of the sets $V$ and $W$ is empty, thus not "qualifying" for disconnectedness.
Since both sets have to contain elements of the union, $A$ and $B$ have to be subsets of different parts of the open covering. So without loss of generality (by renaming sets), we can assume
$$A\subset V, B\subset W.$$
Then, we have
$$B\cap V\subset W\cap V = \emptyset,$$ so that we have found an open neighborhood of $B$ that does not intersect with $A$. This means $$B \cap \overline{A} = \emptyset,$$ the same applies to $A$ with roles reversed. This completes $"\Leftarrow"$.

Now for $"\Rightarrow"$ we want to find a contradiction. Assume $A\cup B$ to be connected and suppose $$\overline{B}\cap A \cup \overline{A}\cap B = \emptyset.$$ But this means
$$A\subset X\setminus \overline{B} \text{ and } B\subset X\setminus\overline{A},$$ by defining $X\setminus \overline{B} =: V$ and $B\subset X\setminus\overline{A} =:W$ we have two nonempty open sets that cover $A\cup B$.
Now we take a look at their intersection:
$$V\cap W = (X\setminus \overline{B}) \cap (X\setminus \overline{A}) = X\setminus (\overline{A}\cup\overline{B})\subset X\setminus (A\cup B).$$
This means that the intersection of these two sets is empty with respect to the subspace topology on $A\cup B$, contradicting connectedness of $A\cup B$. This completes $"\Rightarrow"$.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, everybody! I've glanced over your proof in order to not give myself any revealing details and just get the gist of it. As far as I know now, this is the proof:

Firstly, to prove the $\Leftarrow$ implication, we assume that A$\cup$B is connected. This means that there exist V,W in $\tau$ which fulfil the following characteristics:

1. A$\cup$B$\subset$V$\cup$W

2)(A$\cup$B)$\cap$V$\neq$$\emptyset\$$\neq$(A$\cup$B)$\cap$W

3)(A$\cup$B)$\cap$V$\cap$W=$\emptyset$

Note that 1) implies both A$\subset$V$\cup$W and B$\subset$V$\cup$W. Similarly, 3) implies both A and B are disjoint from V$\cap$W.

Since A and B are connected, the only way for them to be is if they don't fulfil condition 2). Likewise, the only way for that to happen(since A$\cup$B is a subset of V$\cup$W) is if they are "one by one" disjoint from V and W, as in A is disjoint from V and B is disjoint from W (let's take it that is the relation, although it could very well be the other way around).

In that case, it must be that A$\subset$W and B$\subset$V. So we have found an open set containing B (which implies an open neighborhood of all points in B(I know this intuitively, but how to prove it??)), which does not intersect with A. Therefore, it must be that none of the points in B are in the closure of A, or in other words, B$\cap$A$\overline$=$\emptyset$. We then have reached a contradiction, proving what we wanted to.

For the $\Rightarrow$ implication,we assume that A$\cup$B is connected and, supposing  cl(B)$\cap$A$\cup$cl(A)$\cap$B=$\emptyset$, we want to reach a contradiction. This means that both cl(B)$\cap$A and cl(A)$\cap$B=$\emptyset$ are empty, which implies that A$\subset$X\cl(B) and

B$\subset$X\cl(A), where (X\cl(B))$\cap$(X\cl(A))$\subset$X\(A$\cup$B). Notice that both X\cl(B) and X\cl(A) are open sets, thus "disconnecting" A$\cup$B, which contradicts our assumption. This completes the proof.

(I admit for the second implication I just read your proof lol)